# Can't change dbpath for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm unable to change dbpath for mongoDB (WSL2 Arch), I run the bellow command:

```
 sudo mongod --dbpath /home/arijit/work/data/
```

Permission for data folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb mongodb 4096 Aug  9 10:00 data/
```

Error message I'm getting:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-09T11:55:45.163+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-09T11:55:45.228+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-09T11:55:45.229+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-09T11:55:45.231+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":2643,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/home/arijit/work/data/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"ARIJIT-PC-wsl"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-09T11:55:45.231+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.0","gitVersion":"563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-09T11:55:45.231+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Arch","version":"rolling"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-09T11:55:45.232+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"/home/arijit/work/data/"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-09T11:55:45.268+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-09T11:55:45.389+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-09T11:55:45.389+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}
```

I have tried to delete /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock file and then run the command for change dbpath but same result.

Answer (score 10):

Based on @Gibbs answer, the error means the port is already in use another process. You can check and confirm this with

```
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep mongod
```

The output should look like this

```
user 73044   0.2  0.2  5501992  17176   ??  S    11:02AM   0:07.32 mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork
```

where `73044` is the **PID**

You can then kill the process with

```sh
kill -9 <PID> # Replace <PID> with the PID provided in the output...in my case 73044
```

You can now try starting **mongod** again with

```
mongod --dbpath /home/arijit/work/data/
```

Answer (score 2):

Error is different

> {"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}

It means port is already being used by another process.

Try checking `ps -ef | grep portConfigured`. Default mongo port is `27017`

If another process is running in the port, then you have to change port by passing `--port portNumber` while starting mongo.

Comment: I don't think port 27017 is in use. After executing `ps -ef | grep portConfigured` I got `arijit      1910      10  0 15:40 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto portConfigured`

Comment: And `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` gives `mongod  1718 mongodb   11u  IPv4  17670      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:27017 (LISTEN)
node    2579  arijit   20u  IPv6  20045      0t0  TCP *:45999 (LISTEN)`

Comment: after executing `ps -ef | grep 27017`  I got  `arijit      4476      10  0 20:33 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 27017`

Comment: OK, did you configure any port? Can you check using netstat to make sure no mongod is running and grep 27017 port to make sure no job is occupying the port